# How to pass data into components in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this

```
<template id="vButton">
    <button v-bind:title="name">{{name}}</button>
</template>

<div id="app">
    <ti-button></ti-button>
</div>
```

js

```
    Vue.component('ti-button', {
        props: ['name'],
        template: '#vButton'
    });

    var vm2 = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            name : 'hi'
        }
    });
```

I want the button to have innerText and title attribute to say 'hi'. But it does not. Does anyone know why?

Ref: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Thanks

Comment: You need use `<script type="text/x-template" id="vButton">` instead of template tag

Comment: I tried that but the component doesn't show up at all. Before it showed, just not the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
Vue.component('ti-button', {
  props: ['name'],
  template: '#vButton'
});

var vm2 = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    name: 'hi'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script type="text/x-template" id="vButton">
  <div>
    <button>{{name}}</button>
    <button>{{$root.name}}</button>
  </div>
</script>

<div id="app">
  <ti-button name="first_button"></ti-button>
</div>
```

UPD:
Do you mean you don't see this?
[image]

Comment: I answered your comment in the answer.

Comment: i confirm, it works fine with me like in the screenshot, so i think @omega would have an error that prevents the display

Answer (score 0):

You are doing things mostly right, you just need to pass your data to your prop using a `v-bind`:

```
<ti-button v-bind:name="name"></ti-button>
```

Static values can be passed without `v-bind` but for dynamic values like you are attempting to pass you need to bind the prop.  [Check out the static/dynamic prop documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-Static-or-Dynamic-Props) for more information.

And here is a working demo: https://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/qJpzMQ